# The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. Error getting access token from microsoft.com

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory

I am using firebase for microsoft login in my flutter application. I have configured the **App Register** in the **Azure Active Directory**.

- Added the **Redirect URL** from the Firebase console.
- Added the Application secret code from the **certificate & secrets -> client secrets value column**
- Added the Redirect URL to the **Mobile and desktop applications -> Custom URL**
- Set **YES** for **Allow public client flows**
- Set **Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)** for **Supported account types**

**Code for Login:**

```
Future<void> signInMicrosoft() async {
    final MicrosoftAuthProvider microsoftProvider = MicrosoftAuthProvider();
    microsoftProvider.addScope("openid");
    try {
      final UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(microsoftProvider);
      print(userCredential.additionalUserInfo);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (exception) {
      log("${exception.message}");
    }
  }
```

When i try to login the redirect URL is working fine and i was asked to enter the email id and password.Once i enter it throws the error below.

```
The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Error getting access token from microsoft.com, OAuth2 redirect uri is: https://profiler-494e5.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler, response: OAuth2TokenResponse{params: error=invalid_request&error_description=AADSTS90023:%20Public%20clients%20can't%20send%20a%20client%20secret.%0D%0ATrace%20ID:%2060ddccef-1073-4516-a5a5-1f18e50d5800%0D%0ACorrelation%20ID:%20a5a859ce-942e-4428-bd8c-5b30df0d1ae0%0D%0ATimestamp:%202023-05-20%2016:59:00Z&timestamp=2023-05-20%2016:59:00Z&trace_id=60ddccef-1073-4516-a5a5-1f18e50d5800&correlation_id=a5a859ce-942e-4428-bd8c-5b30df0d1ae0, httpMetadata: HttpMetadata{status=400, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE, cacheDurationJava=null, cacheImmutable=false, staleWhileRevalidate=null, filename=null, lastModified=null, retryAfter=null, crossOriginEmbedderPolicy=null, crossOriginOpenerPolicy=null, crossOriginResourcePolicy=null, headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK, contentSecurityPolicies=[], originTrials=[], reportToHeaders=[], varyHeaderNames=[], cookieList=[]}} ]
```

I am not sure what i am missing. I have tried to add android in the authentication but i was not able to set the redirect URL.

Comment: As you enabled `Allow public client flows` to **Yes**, you cannot send client secret in access token request. So, try removing client secret from code while acquiring access token.

Comment: I have added the client secret code to the firebase console only.@Sridevi

Comment: @Sridevi I have give **NO** to `Allow public client flows` and its still the same

Answer (score 3):

Finally I have solved this issue. This error occurred because I didn't register the application properly in the Azure Portal.

- Create an Microsoft account. **(I used Hotmail)**
- Go to [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/#home) and login with your Microsoft Account
- Go to Azure Active Directory. **NOTE: If you can't find it. You can search it by name.**

[image: Azure Port]

- From the left side menu select **App Registrations**

[image: App Registrations]

- Select **New Register** at the top

[image: New Register]

- Give a name and select **Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)** So that you can login with any Microsoft account.

[image: Add App]

- For the redirect url select **Web** from the dropdown and paste the redirect url from the firebase console

[image: Select App Type]

- For the Application ID in the Firebase console copy the **Application (client) ID** from the **overview**

[image: overview]

[image: Application ID]

- Go to Authentication and enable the checkbox **Access tokens (used for implicit flows)** and **ID tokens (used for implicit and hybrid flows)** and save. **Note: Don't give Yes to Allow public client flows**

[image: Authentication 1]

[image: Authentication 2]

- Go to **Certificates & secrete** and select **Client Secrets** tab.

[image: Certificates & secrete]

- Add **New client secret** and copy The ID from **value** column and paste it in the **Application secret** in Firebase Console. **Note: Not the Secret ID**

[image: Application secret]

That's it. Now you are ready to Go.

If you need addition information's from the user . you can add the Permissions in **API Permissions** in the left menu.

For reference [Medium Article](https://ahmadelshafee28.medium.com/flutter-auth-using-firebase-oauth-and-azure-ad-a6f01b6d584)