# Flutter Firebase Microsoft login - invalid_credential

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement microsoft login in my flutter app. I have added the client ID and secret to firebase auth console and called the below method to sign in to microsoft.

```
final microsoftProvider = MicrosoftAuthProvider();

Future microsoftSignIn(context) async {
try {
  final mUser = await firebaseAuth.signInWithProvider(microsoftProvider);
  print('User: $mUser');

} catch (e){
  if (e is FirebaseAuthException) {
    print('Firebase Auth Error Code: ${e.code}');
    print('Firebase Auth Error Message: ${e.message}');
  } else {
    return e.toString();
  }
}
```

}

However, after i successfully signed in to microsoft, i get the following error from Firebase auth saying there is an "invalid-credential" error:

> I/flutter (12035): Firebase Auth Error Code: invalid-credential

> I/flutter (12035): Firebase Auth Error Message: HttpMetadata{status=400, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE, cacheDurationJava=null, cacheImmutable=false, staleWhileRevalidate=null, filename=null, lastModified=null, retryAfter=null, crossOriginEmbedderPolicy=null, crossOriginOpenerPolicy=null, crossOriginResourcePolicy=null, headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK

> I/flutter (12035): , contentSecurityPolicies=[], originTrials=[], reportToHeaders=[], varyHeaderNames=[], cookieList=[]}} ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76296469/the-supplied-auth-credential-is-malformed-or-has-expired-error-getting-access-t), fixed the error by changing the Authentication platform on azure portal from "Mobile & Desktop Apps" to Web". Including checking Access Token and ID tokens. Refer to screenshot below:

[image: Authentication settings]